# Indian travelling by road through Cambodia, Laos and Vietnam

Tags: indian-citizens, vietnam, southeast-asia, cambodia, laos

I intend to do a month-long travel through Cambodia, Laos and Vietnam. I think flying in/out the region from India and then travelling across these regions on road will help me get a budget trip.

How feasible is this plan and what are the visa requirements? I own an Indian passport.

Comment: your second question is regarding itinerary, is off topic. we can only answer your first question

Comment: @Bharag I edited your question just to make it on topic, otherwise it would have been close

Answer (score 3):

- For the visa, you might get the visa on arrival in Laos or Cambodia but have to get the approval letter for it before getting into Vietnam.
- You should start from Laos Airport (Vientiane or Luang Prabang), south by road to Cambodia then Vietnam. And it depends on the length of the trip, your departure airport may be Ho Chi Minh City or Ha Noi City in Vietnam.
  Have a good trip!